# Wrong information obtained\inserted into struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, hash

I'm trying to implement a Hash Table with a struct. 
My intention is to read information from file, then insert it to an array of struct using Hash table.
The code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        FILE *resfile, *reqfile, *repfile;
        char c[MAX_LINE_LENGTH], *token, *refer;
        int i = 0;
        dummyItem = malloc(sizeof(struct resource));
        dummyItem->ID = -1;  
        dummyItem->qty = -1; 
        dummyItem->name = NULL;  
        resfile = fopen("resources.txt", "r");
        reqfile = fopen("requests.txt", "r");
        repfile = fopen("repairs.txt", "r");
        //Initialize a
        while(fgets(c, 100, resfile) != NULL){
            refer = c;
            token = strsep(&refer, "\t");
            long ID = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
            char* name = strsep(&refer, "\t");
            token = strsep(&refer, "\t");
            long qty = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
            insert(ID, name, qty);
            i++;
        }

        for(i = 0; i<MAX_RESOURCES_NUM; i++) {

            if(arr[i] != NULL)
            printf("%ld, %s, %ld\n",arr[i]->ID,arr[i]->name, arr[i]->qty);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

insert function:

```
void insert(long id,char* name, long qty) {
   int hashIndex = hashCode(id);
   while(arr[hashIndex] != NULL && arr[hashIndex]->ID != -1) {
      ++hashIndex;
      hashIndex %= MAX_RESOURCES_NUM;
   }
   arr[hashIndex] = malloc(sizeof(struct resource));
   arr[hashIndex]->ID = id;
   arr[hashIndex]->name = name;
   arr[hashIndex]->qty = qty;
}
```

structure declaration and hash code function:

```
struct resource {
    long ID;
    char* name;
    long qty;
};
struct resource* arr[MAX_RESOURCES_NUM];
struct resource* dummyItem;
int hashCode(long key) {
   return key % MAX_RESOURCES_NUM;
}
```

Input txt file:(ID NAME QTY)

```
13  car lift    8
17  front alignment 2
03  headlights adjust   2
10  oil drain   4
23  computerized check  2
35  pneumatic drive 4
40  ceiling winch   2
99  John Smith  1
29  air compressor  1
66  flats tub   1
88  paint gun   1
```

The problem is that when the results are printed, the name is "paint gun" for all array pointers:

```
    3, paint gun, 2
10, paint gun, 4
13, paint gun, 8
66, paint gun, 1
17, paint gun, 2
23, paint gun, 2
29, paint gun, 1
35, paint gun, 4
88, paint gun, 1
40, paint gun, 2
99, paint gun, 1
```

As you can see, the ID has been inserted properly and it's unique for every pointer, but for some reason the NAME is "paint gun" for all.
It's even stranger because if I add this line at the end of 'insert' function:

```
    printf("INSERTED %ld, %ld, %s, %ld\n", hashIndex,arr[hashIndex]->ID,arr[hashIndex]->name, arr[hashIndex]->qty);
```

I do get the correct information:

```
INSERTED 13, 13, car lift, 8
INSERTED 17, 17, front alignment, 2
INSERTED 3, 3, headlights adjust, 2
INSERTED 10, 10, oil drain, 4
INSERTED 23, 23, computerized check, 2
INSERTED 35, 35, pneumatic drive, 4
INSERTED 40, 40, ceiling winch, 2
INSERTED 49, 99, John Smith, 1
INSERTED 29, 29, air compressor, 1
INSERTED 16, 66, flats tub, 1
INSERTED 38, 88, paint gun, 1
```

Help will be very appreciated !

Comment: You're inserting a pointer to the same `name` array every time. You need to make a copy of it.

Comment: You read each line into the same (confusingly-named) array `c`, overwriting the previous one. `strtok` will return a pointer to the start of the name in `c`, and you insert that pointer into the hash table, but the data it points to is still in the array that gets overwritten when the next line is read.

Comment: Why are you not checking those return values from open?

Comment: @Barmar That was it, ofcourse. Don't know how I have missed it.